# PDO Sqlsrv not showing in phpinfo - Centos 7 PHP 7

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, centos7, sqlsrv

We installed the php_pdo_sqlsrv extension for centos 7, following the recommendations in:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/rhel/

We tested the connection via PDO directly from the command prompt, and everything works perfectly.

When running phpinfo the extension is not recognized, resulting in errors when running the same scripts in the browser:

[image: MODULES]

[image: TEST CONNECTION BY CONSOLE]

[image: MODULES IN NAVEGATOR]

[image: PHP INFO]

[image: INFO EXTENSION]

Has anyone else had this same problem?

Comment: Perhaps maybe because php cli and the webserver use different php.ini?

Comment: All right, I'll check!

Comment: [root@webdeveloperbase]  /usr/lib64/php/modules  $ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d

Comment: phpinfo result path:

Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini

Comment: You might want to `echo php_ini_loaded_file()` in a browser.

Comment: result in a browser /etc/php.ini

Comment: phpinfo - Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php-zts.d

Comment: php --ini - Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d

Comment: I checked the two folders (php-zts.d and php.d), and in all are pointing to pdo_sqlsrv.ini

Comment: check these two files and enable it in both: cli/php.ini & fpm/php.ini

Comment: Sorry, I cant help you further. In distros that I used usually the ini files are placed in /etc/php and it contains different config for cli, apache, fpm and cgi...where I need to enable the extension explicitly for each one

Answer (score 0):

please remove `php-fpm` extension and install again